# Restructure tables on an existing website, to store historical data?

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization, database-relations

I've been trying to find a match for my issue in existing questions, and I'll accept links as an answer and close my question if you have them.

What I'm trying to find is a way to restructure my existing tables.  I have a website, and I spent kind of a long time working on it.  Now I have all the tables and selects in place.  Unfortunately, the "First Name" "Last Name" table is changing a lot, as users update their info.  I want to store historical data for these fields, so I can find users by their real names after they've changed them.  The names aren't unique, but they're easier to remember than their ID numbers.  So, I have a member's table with the fields (username, email, firstname, middlename, familyname, dob, password, country).  Should I just create new tables for firstname and familyname so that I can store the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I got out of the situation so
Created a table with this kind of fields.

```
| Id | id_user | name_field | value | date |
```

I think a lot of clear ... "`name_field`" is that the user has changed ... (Name, Country, etc.)
"`value`" that was in the cell and the "`date`" when there was a change

Comment: I don't just want the date there was a change, though.  I also want to be able to look users up by previous names.

Comment: What's the problem. simple selection of tables for a user ID to give you all his changes

Comment: Oh, okay.  Then how do you select by previous usernames?

Comment: select value from table where namefield='username' and id_user=:ID order by date limit 1

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the answer is YES. Add new fields for first/family name, and find a decent algorithm for converting "fullname" to "first" and "last" (there are many out there, you can even use [excel](http://www.bluemoosetech.com/microsoft-excel-functions.php?jid=32&title=Separating%20First%20and%20Last%20Names%20in%20Microsoft%20Excel))

Comment: So add a fullname field, delete the lastname field... but how do you deal with the historical data?

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I've interpreted your question correctly:
You currently have a table with the fields
 `username, email, firstname, middlename, familyname, dob, password, country` 
and you want to store history for the firstname and familyname columns. Is that correct?

If so, I'd recommend adding time validity columns to your table (valid_from, valid_until), and insert new rows for each change, setting the "valid_from" for the current record to now(), and valid_until to null. You also set the valid_until column of the last row for this user to now(). 
The current record is the one where valid_until is null.

This design is self describing, though it would be better if you stored changes for all fields in the table - not just first and family names. It also allows you to store password history.

The table would be something like:

```
id
username
email
firstname
middlename
familyname
dob
password
country
valid_from
valid_until
```

For instance:

```
    id    username    email    firstname    familyname    ...    valid_from    valid_until
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1      bob        bob@b.com Bob          Smith                1/Jan/2011    null
```

When Bob changes his family name, this becomes

```
    id    username    email    firstname    familyname    ...    valid_from    valid_until
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1      bob        bob@b.com Bob          Smith                1/Jan/2011    1/Aug/2011
   1      bob        bob@b.com Bob          Brown                1/Aug/2011    null
```

Comment: So are you saying I should have one long table with `| Id | id_name | name_field | name_value | name_from | name_until | id_lastname | lastname_field | lastname_value | lastname_from | lastname_until |` and so-on, for email, firstname, middlename, etc., etc.?

Comment: Added an example to my answer

Comment: Yes - I assumed that the ID was some kind of user identifier, and should be preserved. If the column is meaningless, you can increment the ID to make it unique; if you need to preserve it, you can add a primary key